# Perform selector just after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I need to upload some left-over data to server in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but it takes some time and eventually the app may be killed as it cannot finish launching in time, so I used:

```
[myObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]
```

with 0.2f delay, to let `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` finish, but it does not look like a good idea, so I wonder is there a way I can perform the selector just after `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

I know there are `applicationDidBecomeActive` but I need it to be executed in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a delay of 0, it will be executed as soon as control returns to the runloop.

However, if this is blocking for too long in appDidFinishLaunching, then it will also block no matter when you run it. You really should move this code to a background thread. Synchronous network access on the main thread is never a good idea.

Comment: Do you mean if the delay is 0, then it will be executed after appDidFinishLaunching?

Comment: @hzxu effectively, yes he does. It may not be the very next thing (eg if you called with a delay of 0 twice in succession then both couldn't be next) but there'll be no artificial pause. However his main point about the network access stands. Look particularly at `NSURLConnection +sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` — it's exactly as simple as a synchronous send but without blocking. There's really no excuse not to use it.

Comment: @Tommy Yes I know, the network is asynchronous, but I also need to do some Core Data stuff in that method, which has to be on main thread.

Comment: @hzxu Core Data stuff doesn't have to be on the main thread if you run two contexts with the same persistent store coordinator and either write a little shim to synchronise them or treat one as a read-only snapshot. But that's a whole other can of worms and I can understand why you'd decide to ignore the issue if this is the only troublesome case.

Comment: You could also use the asynchronous version of the API to run the network connection on the main thread without blocking. This way you can still use your normal MOC.